# How can I create a random 256 bit integer in Dart?

Tags: math, dart

I would like to create a random (uniformly distributed) 256bit integer in Dart.
Dart's Random only support 32 bit integers. Any ideas?

Comment: Years later we have the benefit of https://pub.dev/documentation/fixnum/latest/fixnum/Int64/Int64.fromInts.html which does the bit-twiddling to get from two unsigned 32-bit ints to a single signed 64-bit int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```dart
import "dart:math";

// 16bit, because random.nextInt() only supports (2^32)-1 possible values.
const PARTS = 16;  // 256bit / 16bit

void main() {
  Random rand = new Random();
  int combinedVal = 0;
  // random parts
  for(var i=0;i<PARTS;i++) {
    int part = rand.nextInt(1<<16); // 2^16
    print("Part $i: $part");
    // shift the 16bit blocks to the left and append the new block
    combinedVal <<= 16;
    combinedVal += part;
    print("Combined: $combinedVal");
  }
  print("Final Result: $combinedVal");
}
```

Output (console application):

```
Part 0: 4273569419
Combined: 4273569419
Part 1: 2298770505
Combined: 18354840894089491529
Part 2: 1076269765
Combined: 78833441363397765815400305349
Part 3: 500743884
Combined: 338587052486927055616611084622869610188
Part 4: 1660193956
Combined: 1454220317280387171410917722806313469431388605604
Part 5: 1335995533
Combined: 6245828703898006563427837796799909693532109776937558322317
Part 6: 2409230726
Combined: 26825630019660005909515912993248305589473794217828668028446551175558
Part 7: 3743170719
...
```

**EDIT**

As Darshan Computing pointed out in the comments, to make this work with dart2js, some modifications are needed, and this would result in lost precision. To use this with browser, an external library and [js interop](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/) would be needed. As an example, i used Leemon Baird's [public domain BigInt library](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.js)

HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Web Playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="web_playground.css">
    <script src="BigInt.js"></script> <!-- this is the important part -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Web Playground</h1>
    <script type="application/dart" src="web_playground.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Dart file:

```dart
import "dart:html";
import "package:js/js.dart" as js;

void main() {
  var rand = js.context.randBigInt(256,0);
  window.alert(js.context.bigInt2str(rand,10));
}
```

Comment: I hoped for something less explicit, but thanks for the reply anw.

Comment: It should really be noted that this only works in the Dart VM.  OP didn't specify whether browser support was needed; it may well be.

Comment: @DarshanComputing good point. it is possible (if the browser itself supports it), but you have to work around dart2js a little bit. editing answer.

Comment: @MarioP The issue is that JavaScript doesn't support big ints, and the Dart team hasn't figured out what they're going to do about that yet. Compiled to JavaScript, you're stuck with doubles.  Which makes your updated code not fulfill the requirements for a 256-bit integer, either.

Comment: @DarshanComputing Oh. Well, seems the only way is to use JS-interop with a BigInt JS library then.

Comment: I might be wrong, but the way I read [the docs](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_math/Random.html#nextInt), the value 4294967295 you pass to `nextInt` is an *exclusive* bound, so that value itself will never be returned. Which means you miss out on 1/4294967296 of all possible values. Whether that is an issue depends on the application, but it should be noted.

Comment: @MvG You could be right. Edited again, to use 16bit blocks. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the comments below, I found that depending on the execution environment, you [`int` class](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/int.html) might be arbitrary size or restricted to 53 bits.

In the former case, you can simply construct a random value from multiple snippets using shift operators. Since [`nextInt`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_math/Random.html#nextInt) does not support an inclusive maximum of 2<sup>32</sup> − 1 (its `max` argument allows that value, but it is *exclusive*, so you get one less posisble value), you might want to do this in chunks of 16 bits. Start with zero, and in every step shift the current value left by 16 bits before adding another 16-bit integer (i.e. one with 2<sup>16</sup> as the `max` argument). After 16 iterations you'll have accumulated 256 bits.

When compiled to JavaScript, `int` has only 53 significant bits. In that case, you'll have to have an arbitrary size integer implementation, either using some third party library or written yourself, perhaps based on ideas from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic. Once you have a big integer class, generating a random element should be easy, as most likely the internal representation of the big integers will consist of 16 or 32 bit units in any case.

Comment: @MarioP Sure, in the Dart VM.

Comment: @MarioP: thanks a lot, I missed that detail. Adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: The limitation of the JS version is temporary until http://dartbug.com/1533 is fixed.

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin Yes, the idea is that it will eventually be fixed, so in that sense it's "temporary".  Someday we will have arbitrary-precision integers everywhere Dart runs.  This is a very real and very relevant problem to be aware of until then.

Comment: In Dart 2.6 there are 1<<32 values, not (1<<32)-1, according to https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-math/Random/nextInt.html:

Generates a non-negative random integer uniformly distributed in the range from 0, inclusive, to max, exclusive.

Implementation note: The default implementation supports max values between 1 and (1<<32) inclusive.